# Why a matrix is a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

I know $L:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ by the formula $L(x)=Ax$ is a linear map. But I cannot understand why the matrix $A$, just itself, is a linear map.

This question came to my mind by the following sentences by Serge Lang

> If $A$ is a square $n \times n$ matrix, then an eigenvector of $A$ is 
>   by definition  an eigenvector of the  linear  map of $K^n$ into 
>   itself represented by **this matrix**. Thus an eigenvector $X$ of $A$ is
>   a (column) vector of $K^n$ for  which there exists $\lambda \in K$
>   such that $AX = \lambda X$.

Comment: By abuse of language sometimes it is assumed that $A$ and $L$ are the same thing. Note that in fact $L$ is uniquely determined by $A$ and $A$ is uniquely determined by $L$.

Comment: Just a note: it's incredibly frustrating trying to read something that is unreadable in the first place. For example when reading the quoted sentence I have no idea what $\mathbf{K}$ is or represents from your standpoint .

Comment: @user2485710 $K$ is an arbitrary field.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ is not a linear map, but it defines a linear map via multiplication $x\mapsto Ax$. Moreover, any linear map can be represented by a matrix when you fix a basis for the domain and the codomain, and hence matrices and linear maps are in one-to-one correspondence. For this reason, sometimes people think of linear maps and matrices as the same.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the passage's complete operative phrase: **represented by this matrix**.

Lang is *not* saying that a matrix in and of itself is a linear map, but that a matrix $A$ of size $n\times n$ is the representation of a linear map $f:K^n \to K^n$ using the standard coordinate basis for $K^n$ and (thus) regular matrix multiplication of vectors in $K^n$ by $A$.

This notion of a matrix representing a linear mapping between finite dimensional vectors spaces, conditioned on a choice of basis for the domain and codomain, is commonly covered in the first course in linear algebra at an undergraduate level.